# android reload layout resource programmatically

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I have an app in which I override the `onConfigurationChanged` because I don't want the activity to be destroyed and rebuilt. it works fine.

Now I want a certain part of the layout to change when the orientation is changed. Regularly I would do this with the `layout-land` folder and that would work, but now it doesn't. The portrait layout stays even when I change to landscape, though it is obviously redrawn, because the items in it change their locations accourding to the new orientation limits.

I think that's because the layout is only redrawn but the resource isn't re-selected from the res folders.

Any idea? (I wouldn't want to use `setLayoutResource` or something alike, I would rather to use the more general solution).

thanks.

Comment: post your code in onConfigurationChanged(). so that people will how your loading the new layout and will be easy to help you better.

Comment: thanks for you help. I don't do there anything related to the layout. but I do call super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); there.

Answer (score 0):

Without `onConfigurationChanged` android redraw the scene by it's own (it `setLayouResource` according to the orientation).

When you write `onConfigurationChanged` you say to OS that you will handle all thing by hands and with `onConfigurationChanged` android only rotate the corresponding view. If you want to use layout from layout-land the only way is to call `setLayouResource` (or move views (change it's layout parameters) dynamically - but this way is not very good) and restore all of your data.

Comment: thanks. I call there super, but still it doesn't reload the layout. It would be a mess to call setLayoutResource again because i'm talking about a certain part in the app that is actually a widget from another android project, and I want to reload only this. I can't reload everything because I have a videoview and i want it to keep playing. I love the way that Android simply rotates the VideoView without stopping anything.

Comment: you can delete your onconfigchanges and after rotating your device onCreate will be called and in this onCreate you can restore state with saved bundle. There is no way (i don't know it and i think it's quite unreal to exist) to reload you layout ith new one without restoring your state. I think you even can save state of the video to restore position and play from it.

Comment: I have added a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67705242/6854117) can you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest insert the parameter: android:configChanges="orientation" on the activity.

Comment: I have added a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67705242/6854117) can you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
}
```

and provide two versions of **yourlayout.xml**: `layout/yourlayout.xml` and `layout-land/yourlayout.xml`. You can add more - for different sizes, etc.

Don't forget to set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`, otherwise your activity may be reloaded.

Comment: It's more complex than that because i have a VideoView that I want to keep playing after the orientation change, and some other parts of the layout to change. Finally I had to recreate the other parts of the layout with each orientation change. thanks anyway

Comment: I have added a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67705242/6854117) can you please check it out?